# CodeIgniter: один шаблон на все страницы

Tags: ajax, php, codeigniter

Вообщем, цель была сделать так, чтобы был один общий шаблон, контент там статичен меняется только в меин блоке (с помощью ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то первым контроллером при заходе выступает контроллер welcome. Либо все в шаблоне welcome правите, либо свой делаете, а в контроллере имя шаблона меняете.
А остальные контроллеры уже чисто json-данные отдают.

Comment: Не много вас не понял. Есть контроллер, простая страничка, допустим. Если я его подгружу к примеру http://localhost/index.php/welcome/ отобразиться информация из index(), все ок, если я нажму на ссылку(находясь в этом контроллере) у меня подгрузиться в нужный мне блок допусти информация из http://localhost/index.php/world/hello, но вот если я напрямую перейду к  http://localhost/index.php/world/hello, соответственно отоброзиться только информация, без хедере и футера...

Comment: Ааааа. Так можно: делайте модуль, отвечающий за отображение. Ему для рендеринга передаете названия страниц: header, footer, main.
В конфигах подгружаете его, чтобы в каждом контроллере не подгружать.

Comment: А вообще почитайте доки, там должно быть подобное.

Comment: Читаю, но не вижу...

Comment: сделайте стандартную вьюху и в ней подгружайте (`$this->load->view()`) по условию `!$this->input->is_ajax_request()` хедер и футер (я как понимаю контент у вас просто html, не json) не знаю как во втором, в 3м это катило, ну или в контроллере это делайте.

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://www.prostosem.in.ua/article/shablon_dlya_vyivoda_stranicyi_v_codeigniter) подробно расписано о создании шаблона страницы для Codeigniter, ну а прикрутить AJAX уже не составит труда